# Tell fetch() to not send a Content-Type header at all

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, content-type

Is there a way to send an HTTP request with `fetch()` and tell it to not automatically set a header? I'm trying to get it to send a request without a `Content-Type`, I can get it to send an empty header

```http
Content-Type:
```

like this

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8000/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': ''
  },
  body: 'some data'
});
```

but can I get it to not include the line at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per step 36 of https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-request and https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-bodyinit-extract, a `fetch`-initiated request with a request body will always end up with a `Content-Type` header — because there are only two possible paths a request with a request body can take in the spec:

1. If you don’t specify any `Content-Type` header at all in your `fetch` call, then the browser always automatically on its own sets a `Content-Type` header for the request; unless…
2. If you specify a `Content-Type` header in your `fetch` call, then the browser uses the value you set.

So because those two are the only possible outcomes and because the `fetch` API doesn’t provide any method for completely removing any browser-set request headers, then if a request has a request body, there’s no way to send the request using the `fetch` API without it ending up with a `Content-Type` header.

Comment: So I guess the answer is "first you send WhatWG a proposal to make `fetch()` treat `null` as a special value for `headers:`...".