# How can I convert this axios call to fetch?

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch, multipartform-data, form-data

I have the follow axios code which works. I get the expected response back:

(some strings altered for obvious reasons)

```
const data = new FormData()

data.append('grant_type', 'password')
data.append('username', 'XXXXX')
data.append('password', 'YYYYY')

const url = 'https://www.example.com/endpoint/'

const config = {
  withCredentials: false,
  auth: {
    username: 'AAAAA',
    password: 'BBBBB'
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}

const response = await axios.post(url, data, config)
const answer = response.data.answer
console.log('answer', answer)
```

I would like to convert this request to fetch, but I am getting a `Bad Request` message back. I have tried:

```
const authorization = btoa('AAAAA:BBBBB')

console.log(authorization)

const data = new FormData()

data.append('grant_type', 'password')
data.append('username', 'XXXXX')
data.append('password', 'YYYYY')

console.log(data)

const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/endpoint/', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'omit',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      Authorization: `Basic ${authorization}`
    },
    body: data
})

console.log(response)
```

Attempting to compare two requests in the Network tab didn't help much. They look nearly identical. The only differences I see in the requests are in the headers:

axios

```
"accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
"content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryxYSW9yII1AMmhcc3",
```

The accept key contains more than just `*/*` and the content-type key contains information on the boundary.

fetch

```
"accept": "*/*",
"content-type": "multipart/form-data",
```

I am not sure if the boundary information is important for the content-type nor how to make sure it is included. I tried modifying the code so the accept key would match, but that did not change behavior.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the two requests in network tab?

Comment: You can go to devtool, network tab, send your request with axios, righr click your request, copy as fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some additional research, what I learned is that when using fetch to post multipart/form-data, the `content-type` should not be defined. This allows the system to construct it and add in the required boundary information. Additionally, the `credentials` setting is not required.

The fetch request should look like:

```
const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/endpoint/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${authorization}`
    },
    body: data
})
```

With this code change, I get the expected response.

For documentation on this behavior, see the answer to [Tell fetch() to not send a Content-Type header at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71670213/tell-fetch-to-not-send-a-content-type-header-at-all/71674192#71674192)