# Where can I find some fetch documentation on autogenerated content-type?

Tags: fetch-api, content-type, code-documentation

If I write some code to do a `fetch` for some `multipart/form-data` which looks like:

```
const authorization = btoa('AAAAA:BBBBB')
const data = new FormData()

data.append('grant_type', 'password')
data.append('username', 'XXXXX')
data.append('password', 'YYYYY')

const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/endpoint/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      Authorization: `Basic ${authorization}`
    },
    body: data
})
```

It will not work. The reason is that when sending the request, the `Content-Type` in the header does not contain the boundary information required.  If instead the `fetch` is written as:

```
const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/endpoint/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Basic ${authorization}`
    },
    body: data
})
```

The request will work because the system will automatically generate the correct `Content-Type` as `multipart/form-data` with the boundary information.

My question is where can I find documentation that it will do this? I have looked around at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch, etc. but my eyes must be glazing over where it is mentioned. I have not found it yet.

Comment: For the relevant spec links and some related explanation, see my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/71674192

Comment: yep, that question is a duplicate of mine. thank you.